# how to convert system date to date with yyyy-MM-dd date format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I want to convert my system date with yyyy-MM-dd date format and assign to another date 
my code is:

```
NSDate *datenow = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
currDate = [df stringFromDate:datenow];

NSLog(@"currDate ====%@",currDate);

[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *compareDate = [df dateFromString:currDate];

NSLog(@"compareDate ====%@",compareDate);
```

NSLog prints like this 
currDate ====2014-05-10
compareDate ====2014-05-10 00:00:00 +0000

I want remove 00:00:00 +0000 in the compare date. How to do it.
please help me it's killing my time.

Comment: *"I want remove 00:00:00 +0000 in the compare date."* - That makes no sense. `NSDate` is just an absolute point in time (stored as seconds since Jan 1, 2001 GMT). NSDate does not know anything about hours, minutes or time zones. What you see in "compareDate ====2014-05-10 00:00:00 +0000" is the `description` of the date object. The description always printed in GTM.

Comment: ... I meant GMT. - Perhaps you can describe what you actually need to achieve.

Comment: Whenever you `NSLog` `NSDate` objects, it will always display it in GMT in that `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000` format. Whenever you want to see it in a particular format (e.g. just `yyyy-MM-dd`, then you should not `NSLog` the `NSDate` object, but rather merely the string representation you retrieved using a `NSDateFormatter`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];`

`// Getting components of the current date.
NSDateComponents *currentDateComponents = [currentCalendar components:NSCalendarCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit  fromDate:[NSDate date]];`

Now you the components of your date (You can pass any date instead of `[NSDate date]` of course) you can use each one of them you want, or you can further use a:

`NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD"];`

to format your date.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I want remove `00:00:00 +0000` in the compare date. How to do I it.

In short, if you don't want to see the date in the UTC string `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000`, then do not `NSLog` the `NSDate` object itself. Only `NSLog` the strings you extract from the `NSDateFormatter`.

---

But, your example code suggest a misconception of the purpose and function of `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` objects.

- A `NSDate` represents a point in time, e.g. 8pm GMT, which is 10pm CEST in Paris or 4pm EDT in New York. But an `NSDate` doesn't include a time zone, as 8pm GMT and 10pm CEST and 4pm EDT all represent the same point in time.
- A `NSDateFormatter` can be used to convert to and from string representations of that `NSDate` object (e.g. so that at 8pm GMT, the user in Paris sees "10pm" whereas the user in New York sees "4pm").

But it makes no sense to use a date formatter to convert a date to a string (and this string will be, by default, in the local time zone), and then convert that string back to a date (this time saying that that string was representing the date/time in UTC, when it was not).

It is equivalent to me standing next to a Frenchman in Times Square in New York City at 4pm EDT and telling him "it's 4pm GMT right now", to which he'll only dismiss me as a crazy American who is too ignorant to know that it's really 8pm GMT (or, according to his watch, 10pm CEST in Paris).

So, perhaps you can step back and tell us what you're trying to do, as the code in your question doesn't make sense. If you convert a date to a string with a date formatter using a particular time zone, then if you want to convert it back to a date, you have to use the same timezone. (Or you have to use a date format which is explicit about the time zone; this is why `NSLog` uses the `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000` format, so that it's unambiguous as to what point in time the `NSDate` represents.)

Answer (score 0):

```
        NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formater setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
        [formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSString *todayString = [formater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSLog(@"todayString ====%@", todayString);
```